# print element from list

Tags: c++, list, element

I have a list that prints out weather data for a year. The data is listed by month and I need to find the yearly totals after the list is sorted. I used the list.sort() function to sort the list by month. From there, I need to print a specific element of data, but I'm unsure how to do so. here's an example of the unsorted list:

```
Weather data:
Month    temp    rainfall
 2        60       2.0    
 4        75       3.4
 1        50       1.5
```

How do I print out a specific temp, or rainfall? In this case, max temp = 75. This the how I used the list.sort():

```
// ListNode class not included
bool shift_Months( ListNode M1, ListNode M2 )
{
     if( M1.getMonth() < M2.getMonth() ) return true;
     return false;
}
int main ()
{
     ListNode M;
     list<ListNode> Mlist;
     list<ListNode>::iterator p;
     int i;

     Mlist.sort( shift_Months );
     for( i=0,p=Mlist.begin(); i<Mlist.size()-1; i++,p++ )
         cout << *p;

     return 0;
 }
```

I was thinking of sorting the list by whatever I need to get. For example, sort by temp, and display the last temp. I don't know how to display only the temp without displaying the rest of the list.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I was thinking of sorting the list by whatever I need to get. For example, sort by temp, and display the last temp.

Sorting is slow. Sorting just to perform analysis on data is baaad.

Why not track maxima and minima as you add items to the list? Perhaps with a wrapper class.

If this is not feasible for whatever reason (and you can live with `O(n)` lookup), you can do a search through the list for the record with the values that you're looking for, but I still wouldn't go modifying the original data for this.

> I don't know how to display only the temp without displaying the rest of the list.

We would need to know what `ListNode` looks like in order to give an exact answer, but I think that you are looking for something like `cout << p->getTemp();`.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, you probably should *not* use an `std::list` for this. You're not showing anything to indicate that it's a good choice, and absent a specific indication in its direction, `std::list` is usually about *last* choice of containers to use. For that matter, even when you think you *do* have a specific indication in its directly, chances are *still* pretty good that it's a mediocre to poor choice.

Second, to get the minimum or maximum value, you normally just want to use `std::min_element` or `std::max_element` respectively:

```
struct by_month { 
    bool operator()(ListNode const &a, ListNode const &b) { 
        return a.GetMonth() < b.GetMonth();
    }
};

std::vector<ListNode> data;

std::cout << std::max_element(data.begin(), data.end(), by_month());
```